# Validate fields on html page with php

Tags: php, html, validation, forms, http-post

Please find code of index.html and submit.php file. With the help of [loopo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32763/loopo), both are working perfect. I am struggling where excatly to put the validation code (in index.html file or submit.php file). i am using html5 input types in html file and I dont know where exactly the validation has to happen in submit.php file. I have multiple forms and I made validations.php as suggested. I am also not understanding where will the error messages been shown?

Can you suggest a location in the submit.php file where I should add these validations by editing my submit.php file? 
Regexp for email (`'/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/'`) 
Regexp for phone (`^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$`)

**index.html file**

```
<form method="post" action="submit.php">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="cl"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" /></div>
        <div class="cl"><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" /></div>
        <div class="cl"><input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile" /></div>
        <div class="cl"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" /></div>
        <div class="cl"><input type="text" name="sub" placeholder="Want 3 m Free Subscription (Yes/No)?"></textarea></div>
        <div class="cl"><input type="text" name="slogan" placeholder="Suggest a slogan for 6 m subscription"></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div class="srow">
        <div class="cl1">
            <ul class="action">
                <li><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**submit.php file**

```
<?php
include 'config.php'; // store your configuration in a seperate file so 
                      // you only need to update it once when your environment changes

$errors = false;
$output = '';
$nl = '<br>'.PHP_EOL;
$redirect_url = 'index.html';

if (!$con = new mysqli(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME)){
    $errors = true;
    $output .= "ERROR Can't connect to DB".$nl;
};   


if (!$errors){
   //should validate/clean $_POST before using in query
   $name = $con->escape_string($_POST['name']);
   $city = $con->escape_string($_POST['city']);
   $email = $con->escape_string($_POST['email']);
   $mobile = $con->escape_string($_POST['mobile']);
   $sub = $con->escape_string($_POST['sub']);
   $slogan = $con->escape_string($_POST['slogan']);

   $sql="INSERT INTO members 
            (sName, sCity, sMobile, sEmail, sSub, sSlogan)
         VALUES ('$name', '$city', '$mobile', '$email',
                '$sub','$slogan')";

   if (!$con->query($sql)){ //forgot a parenthesis here earlier
      $output .= 'ERROR: DB said: ('.$con->errno.') '.$con->error.$nl;
      $output .= 'Query was:'.$sql.$nl;
      $errors = true;
   }else{
     $output .= "1 record added".$nl;
   }
}

if (!$errors){
   //if there are no errors redirect to index.html;
   header('refresh: 2; URL='.$redirect_url);
   $output .= '...Redirecting...'.$nl;
}else{
   //show the errors and allow display a link to go back/try again
   $output .= '<a href="'.$redirect_url.'">Try again</a>'.$nl;
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Validations suggested by [loopo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32763/loopo) but dont know exact location to put it. I made a validations.php file and included in submit.php but may be my syntax is wrong because of which it is not working.

```
function validate_name($input){
    // fairly naive rule:
    // upper and lower case latin characters and space
    // at least three character long
    // you may want to look at allowing other characters such as é ö etc.
    $input = trim($input); //get rid of spaces at either end
    if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]{3,}$/',$input) == 1){
        return $input;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

  if (!empty($_POST['name']){
    if (!$name = $con->escape_string(validate_name($_POST['name'])){
        $error = true;
        $output .= 'ERROR: Invalid Name: '.$_POST['name'].$nl;
    }
  }else{
    $error = true;
    $output .= 'ERROR: No name specified'.$nl;
  }
```

Comment: So all you want to do is to put the validations for email and phone? If so, better put them in the html, don't give the user a chance in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. Actually the record is not getting added in the database. It gives a blank page. I think the bottom code in validations.php file should be put in submit.php but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

html validations can be bypassed by sending a request directly to the php file, so validating info on server-side is a good choice you made.

i suggest you better use php's built-in function [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), for clean code and accurate/safe results, try this:

```
function validateEmail($email){
    if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        return true;
    }
}

function validatePhonenb($nb){
    if(filter_var($nb,FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP,array("options"=>array("regexp"=>"/^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?[789]\d{9}$/"))){
        return true;
    }
}
```

and since there is no validating for phone numbers, i used your regex, btw you can [sanitize](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)the phone number using var_filter before proceeding instead of validating it

> I have multiple forms and I made validations.php as suggested. I am
>   also not understanding where will the error messages been shown

error messages will be shown in the bottom of the page since they are being echoed in the end of the code

```
echo $output;
?>
```

if they are not being displaced change the position of echoing the output containing errors and execute `die()` after it so the script will stop execution after it showed the errors

Comment: Thanks. Where do i put this code, in submit.php or validations.php. If submit.php, at what location should I put it?

Comment: you should have php knowledge to deal with php, anyways this must be in validations.php and called from submit.php

Comment: I agree... I am practicing php.. can you please give me the syntax to call the function from submit.php? Thanks

Comment: if(validateEmail("email@here.com")) { code here } 
if(validatePhonenb("0011234567890")){ code here }

Comment: Thanks. I also understood the issue with the code why it was not working. I was missing parenthesis in the if (!empty($_POST['name']){ line and the following line. Also instead of $error = true; it should have been $errors = true; missed the letter s. I want to ask one thing. When the errors are displayed in case it is not validated, it gives a link to try again but the data entered goes off. How can I get it back?

Comment: i believe you are looking for the autocomplete attribute, this attribute must be added to the form you are submitting, then your form tag must be like this
<form method="post" action="submit.php" autocomplete="on" >

Comment: Well not really... If you see the line      $output .= '<a href="'.$redirect_url.'">Try again</a>'.$nl;     in submit.php file, it redirects to the url and I want the redirection to be the BACK function of browser so that the data entered stays there.